# Python - не работает добавление в словарь

Tags: python, словарь

Начал изучать Python, за 17 часов изучения результат таки есть. Понимание общих понятий уже тоже есть, но с логикой видимо таки проблемы. Ну как я не крутил не понимаю почему не работает. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем причина, ну не добавляет информации в словарь и все. Видимо я чего то не понимаю до конца, хотя и программа вроде как простая - телефонная книга. Сейчас изучаю по Byte of Python.
Спасибо...

```
from os import close
import pickle,sys,time
base = 'adress_book_project_base.txt'
adress_book={}

file = open(base,'wb')
pickle.dump(adress_book,file)
file.close()

command = input('Hello it is your Phone book.You can check/add/remove info from it. Or print exit for Exit -> ')
time.sleep(1)
if command =='exit':
        print('Exit...')
        sys.exit()
elif command == 'check':
        file = open(base,'rb')
        checking=pickle.load(file)
        while True:
                line =file.readline()
                if len(line)==0:
                       print('Your Phonebook is empty')
                break
        for name,phone in adress_book.items():
                print('Person ->{0}phone ->{1}'.format(name,phone))
        file.close()
elif command == 'add':
        file = open(base,'wb')
        add_info_name =input('Please enter the name ->')
        add_info_phone =input('Please enter the phone ->')
        adress_book[add_info_name]=add_info_phone
        print('Was added name- {0}, phone- {1}'.format(add_info_name,add_info_phone))
        pickle.dump(adress_book,file)
        file.close()
```

Comment: Все добавляется. Просто не нужно в начале скрипта обнулять файл дампом пустого словаря `pickle.dump(adress_book,file)`. А также сами данные находятся в `checking` - а далее построчно файл читать бесполезно, ведь а) он не текстовый б) `pickle.load` выставил текущую позицию в конец файла и там нечего читать.

Comment: @vitidev - Большое спасибо! Очень благодарен. Вроде разобрался!

Comment: @Oleksandr_I Советую Вам для работы с файлам изучить `with statement` [ссылка1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/), [ссылка2](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/), [ссылка3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T - Большое спасибо, я работу с обычными текстовыми уже освоил. Но сейчас начал пробовать работать с pickle, пока стараюсь. Ну и за пару дней отличный результат тоже получить тяжело... Большое спасибо еще раз!